# SwiftUI - Overlay TabView with Custom View

Tags: swiftui, overlay, tabbar, tabview

I'm having an app with a tab bar navigation concept. For one view I'm currently trying to implement a tab bar overlay that you all know from the Photos App in iOS. It appears when you select images. See below:

[image: Tab Bar Overlay]

I tried to implement this behavior in the below code snippet but I have two doubts:

- is `.overlay()` the right way to do it? I wanted to combine it with a State and set it accordingly to enable / disable the overlay.
- if overlay is ok from a coding point of view, how would I align it to the bottom and take care of the sizing so that it exactly overlays the tab bar?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            
            NavigationView {
                Text("First Nav Page")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house")
                Text("Home")
                
            }.tag(0)
            
            NavigationView {
                Text("Second Nav Page")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                Text("Settings")
            }.tag(1)
            
            Text("No Nav Page")
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                    Text("Test")
                }.tag(2)
            
        }.overlay(
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey did you end up using the overlay? I'm considering it to add an extra function to the TabView, but not sure how to align it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `Toolbar`, not TabBar. So when the user changes in EditMode, you will have to change the TabBar into the Toolbar.

The Toolbar is available in iOS 14 and takes a ToolbarItem for the Status in the center and a leading Item with your Icon. You should have to build a function which swapes your TabBar with the Toolbar.

Here is a example of the Toolbar for your case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isSelecting : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar, content: {
                            Button(action: {
                                
                            }){
                                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                            }
                        })
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .status, content: {
                            Text("Auswählen")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Happy it helped. Learned a lot too again, didn't know Toolbar in SwiftUI till today

Comment: Been tuning it a little bit but it's really hacky. I also needed to write an extension for conditional modifier (if element = true enable .overlay()). Also styling of the tabbar is challenging. Don't think that Apple did it this way :D Do you know how configure a ZStack to overlay the tabView @davidev ? I would have more styling and condition options in there.